# How do I build a good 'stagger lock' character?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have started a stagger lock build on Dark Souls 2, and I am not doing so well. I am using two daggers and power stance.

I want to be able to stagger lock anything that is not completely immune to the effect. I intend to have high damage output, but I know I will need a lot of upgrading.

What can I do to build a good 'stagger lock' character?

Comment: I understand you wanting to correct my grammar... hardly. But do you have any advice, like really?

Comment: You're going to need to add some more information. Perhaps include your current build, and what you want to change/improve, or what you want to use/aim for. As of right now, this question is way to broad to get *a* good answer.

Comment: Well for one I really would like to deal fair damage, which I am sure I can only do with tons of upgrading. But im also wanting to know how to get it so I can stagger lock almost anything... well anything that it is possible to do so to. I am currently trying a stagger lock role by equipping two beginning daggers and using power stance. I would love to keep just daggers as they are the lightest weapons in the game.

Comment: Tried making this less broad :/ that said, I wouldn't go as far as to say this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thanks timelord64 but do you have any advice

Comment: Also is this for PvP or PvE?

Comment: PVE for the time being. At least until I get good enough to go PVP.

Answer (score 2):

well, **stone ring** is the first item you need for staggering since you stagger the enemy when your **poise damage** is higher than your opponent's **poise**
also heavy weapons like clubs, hammers, ultra greatswords usually have more poise damage than daggers.
also as an extra fact if you're going for a melee build that'll spam on opponent you should have high poise in case of attacking same time with your opponent so I advice you to use **ring of giants +2** too